# How to get sum of the production_volume in a seasion of a particular fiscal_year using Django ORM

Tags: python, django, orm

Here, I'm trying to get the sum of the production_volume different seasons in particular production_year:
here is my models:

```
class FiscalYear(BaseModel, models.Model):
    year = models.CharField(max_length=256)

class Season(BaseModel, models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)    
    season_month = models.ManyToManyField(Month)

class Product(BaseModel, models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='product_category')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    hs_code = models.CharField(max_length=256, unique=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/product/%Y/%M/', null=True, blank=True)
    production_unit = models.ForeignKey(MeasurementUnit, related_name='product_unit', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)


class Production(BaseModel, models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='production_product', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    district = models.ForeignKey(DistrictLevel, related_name='production_district', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    production_volume = models.FloatField()
    production_year = models.ForeignKey(FiscalYear, related_name='production_year', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    seasons = models.ManyToManyField(Season, related_name='product_season')
```

I'm getting result by using for loop, aggregate but I think this is not appropriate. Which is below:

```
        fiscal_year = FiscalYear.objects.all().first() # for test
        for i in Season.objects.all():
            production_year = Production.objects.filter(production_year = fiscal_year).filter(seasons=i).aggregate(total_production = Sum('production_volume'))
            print(production_year ,909090)
```

How can i get result by ORM methods.
I tried by using related_name with aggregate and annotate but it didn't work. Below what I want exactly:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does this help?

```
production_year = Production.objects.filter(production_year = fiscal_year).values('seasons').annotate(total_production = Sum('production_volume'))
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Razenstein. It works for me it gives me better result by use values("seasons__name"). thanks
If my question is appropriate and useful please up this question.